# making a link between columns in order to assign same value

Tags: r

How to make links between 2 columns that are logically connected?

I.e. I have 1 column which is city and second is zip code looking like this :

```
city zipcode
NA      555
NYC     555
NYC      NA
```

So it's obvious that there is a link between them, but how do i force imputing of same values for respective columns if 1 value of either of columns is known?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudocode

```
1. Filter rows in the dataframe that have zipcode as 555
2. For these rows, look for city = NA and impute this with the unique(city) value 

Repeat the same with City 
1. Filter rows in the dataframe that have City = NYC
2. For these rows, look for zipcode = NA and impute this with the unique(zipcode) value 

Both these steps will have to be looped over the entire dataset rows that have NA in any of those 2 columns.
```

Comment: is it possible to put it to automatic since there are 580 values?

Answer (score 0):

With 580 values as you say, the problem is greater than the reprex data above given there's only one ZIP and one city provided.

I'd suggest merging in each column of your data frame after establishing a complete case and then getting the unique complete rows using `distinct`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_2 <- df %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(city, zipcode)) %>% 
  merge(select(df, city), by = "city", all.x = TRUE) %>% 
  merge(select(df, zipcode), by = "zipcode") %>%
  distinct(city, zipcode)
```

from the reprex example this only leaves one row, but with 580 rows I'm assuming you have more than one city and one ZIP code.